# What happens to an open Filestream if it is not close due to program crash?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

What will happen to an open FileStream if it is not close due to a program crash?
Will it be close automatically?
I can't enclose it in a try catch or using because I am doing something with the file.
It's like I open the file with an Open button.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    fs = new FileStream("Test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);          
}
```

Then I do something with it. Then in the Exit or closing of the application I execute close.

```
fs.Close();
```

But what if something happens in between, like a program crash.
Will the file be not accessible since it is not close properly?
Thanks.

Comment: The handle will be automatically closed by the operating system.

Comment: Thanks Matthew.. any links I can give to my boss as a proof? :)

Comment: As you open the FileStream with read/write access, I assume that you are writing data to the file. When your program crashes during such a write operation you may well leave the file in a corrupted state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to find exactly what Windows will do when an application exits, either intentionally or otherwise.

The [Terminating a Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article on MSDN describes what happens when a process is terminated, most notably.

> Any remaining threads in the process are marked for termination.
>   Any resources allocated by the process are freed.
>   All kernel objects are closed.
>   The process code is removed from memory.
>   The process exit code is set.
>   The process object is signaled.

Slightly off-topic, but in your particular piece of code, `FileStream` implements `IDisposable`, so you should research on the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) keyword for information about deterministic resource clean-up.

Answer (score 3):

Actually we cannot know what will happen in such a situation. MSDN says about the [FileStream Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) that

> If a process terminates with part of a file locked or closes a file that has outstanding locks, the behavior is undefined.